# Which artifacts of Cobertura should I check-in to SVN?

Tags: java, svn, cobertura

I have Cobertura integrated with my project, and it works as expected.  However, I am not sure which of the Cobertura artifacts to check-in to SVN.

The directory structure looks something like:

- MainProjectDir
- cobertura.ser
- coberturaDir

  - cssDir
  - imagesDir
  - instrumentedDir
  - js
  - reports
  - LOTS OF html FILES

There is just over 1 MEG of space in the coberturaDir, and checking in that directory seems troublesome for future commits.

My goal is to keep track of the total for the project and each class.

Of the cobertura artifacts, what should I be committing to SVN?

Thanks, 
    Sean

Comment: why would you check any of them into svn?  they are all build artifacts.  if you want to keep them, deploy them to a build site.  there's not need to preserve them in svn _because you can always regenerate them_.

Comment: You should only check what is necessary to build your project into your source control. You shouldn't check in the *output* of your build process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them.

You should be able to regenerate the Cobertura reports by pointing toward an older revision in your version control system. Since the reports are a derivative product of the version of software, there's no need to store them. This is the same principle that applies to generated documentation (javadoc, doxygen) and binary files produced from your source code (jars, exes, class files).

If you need history, I'd suggest saving the report outside of version control, in someplace like a file server. You can then compress old report directories into ZIPs or tarballs so they are available, but archived to reduce space and make finding the latest data easier. You can also take the measurements and metrics that are most important and put them into a single file, such as a spreadsheet, and put that in a file server.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Thomas Owens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12353683/368630) said: None of them.

Ah, you say. I want to be able to see the results and save them. I want to be able to link them back to the developers and see how my test coverage changes over time.

In that case, use a Continuous Integration system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins can examine your XML based Cobertura coverage reports and display them as graphs. It can save these graphs with each build. Each build will show you who made the commit that triggered the build and the changes in coverage since the last build. You can even play a *CI Game* and award points to developers who create Unit tests that expand your coverage. (First prize is a Cadillac Eldorado. Second prize is a set of steak knives, and third prize is you're fired.)

Jenkins is pretty simple to setup and get working. You'll need to download the Cobertura plugin which is pretty easy to do. It'll do what you want without having to check in your Cobertura files.